# Installing Python packages with 64 bit Windows and Python 3.3

Tags: python, window, 64-bit, package

I've read that there's a nice text-to-speech package called pyttsx that can be included in my Python scripts.  As soon as I try to install pyttsx things start falling apart fast.  pyttsx is for Python 2.6 (2.7 maybe?) not 3.3.  I have 2.7 and 3.3 (also Portable Python 2.7 and 3.2) installed but I can't get setuptools or easy_install to work.  I got distribute partly installed but I'm might have seen some errors at the end of its installation so I'm not sure it's working and it won't install pyttsx anyway.  There's a Windows .exe program that will let you install Python packages but it won't work for 64-bit Python.  I've been searching for answers for days can can't come up with anything specific enough.

How do I install Python packages with 64-bit Python 3.3 on 64-bit Windows 7, or is that even possible?

Comment: It depends on the package.  If the package wasn't written for Python 3, it won't work for Python 3.  There are 64-bit installers for many libraries at the site linked by Jakob Bowyer below, but that won't help you install a Python 2 library on Python 3.

Comment: Python 3.3 on Windows allows you to install more than one version of Python and use the Python Loader and a shabang to pick the version to use.  For example I add #python2.7 as the first line to older code to make it work.  Shouldn't pyttsx be installable to version 2.7 on my system?  Can packages be installed manually?

Comment: Yes, you should be able to install it if you have Python 2 installed.  You'll need to give specific information about exactly how you're trying to install it and what errors you're getting.

Answer (score 2):

Best source ever!

[this man is a wicked fellow.](http://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/)

Comment: I remember finding that website.  Thank you! But my package is in another castle.  I mean, what if they don't have the package I want?

Answer (score 2):

With distribute installed, launch the python.exe you want to use.

From within python interactive, run the following code:

```
from setuptools.command import easy_install

easy_install.main(["-U", "package"])
```

Substitute "package" for whatever you wish to install.